# What is the effect of aft centre of pressure movement on static longitudonal stability?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, stability

During studying for my Air Transport Pilot License (ATPL) I encountered a question answer which said that aft center of pressure movement increases longitudinal stability. If this is true, I cannot seem to wrap my head around the concept of why this is so.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out, fixed in original Q

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Moving the CP aft will have the same effect as moving the CG forward: increased longitudinal stability.

The arm of the Lift force is now increased and the ratio of momentum generated by the wing vs horizontal stabilizer is decreased, leading to positive longitudinal stability.